# ¿Cómo actualizar gráfico con HighCharts?¿redraw()?

Tags: jquery, json, highcharts

estoy generando un gráfico con HighCharts, los valores de agua que se insertan des de lunes hasta domingo. Me gustaría que al click en la div con id `#submit_500ml`, me hiciera un redraw del gráfico y se actualizara, pero así como lo he hecho no me funciona.

```
var week = [100,200,300,400,500,600];
$(function () {
    Highcharts.chart('water_grafic', {

    chart: {
        type: 'column',
        backgroundColor:'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)'
    },

    title: { //titol
        text: ''
    },

    legend:{ //llegenda
        display: 'none'     
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sun','Sat'],
        gridLineColor: "#fff",
        lineColor: "#fff",
        lineWidth: 0,
        minorGridLineWidth: 5,
        lineColor: '#fff',      
        minorTickLength: 0,
        tickLength: 0,
        labels: {
            style: {
                color: '#fff'
            },
        },
    },

    yAxis: {
        allowDecimals: false,
        min: 0,
        gridLineColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0.5)",
        lineColor: "#fff",
        labels: {
            style: {
                color: '#fff'
            },
        },
        title: {
            text: '',
            color: '#fff'
        },
        plotLines: [{ //Resaltar línia de baix de la gràfica.
            value: 0,
            width: 1.2,
            color: '#fff'
        }/*,
        { //Útil si definim un valor objectiu del que vol veure d'aigua
            value: 2200,
            width: 1.5,
            color: 'red'
        }*/
        ]
    },

    tooltip: { //El que surt quan cliques a sobre de algun valor de la taula
        formatter: function () {
            return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' +
                this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + '<br/>' +
                'Total: ' + this.point.stackTotal;
        }
    },

    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal'
        }
    },

    series: [{
        showInLegend: false,
        name: '',
        color: '#fff',
        borderRadius: 1,
        data: week
    }],

    credits: { //treiem logo highchart.com
        enabled: false
    },
    exporting: { //treiem botó d'exportar
        enabled: false
    }

});



});

var chart = $('#water_grafic').highcharts();
$('#submit_500ml').on('click', function() {
    chart.yAxis[0].isDirty = true;
    chart.yAxis[0].min= 0;
    chart.yAxis[0].max= 5;
    chart.yAxis[0].tickInterval = 1;
    chart.redraw();
});
```

Comment: ¿Has probado con [update()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Chart.update)?

Comment: Si, `$("#submit_500ml").click(function () {
    chart.update({
        chart: {
            inverted: true,
            
        }
    });
});`, si pongo inverted:true, invierte la grafica i se actualiza, pero deso que se actualice sin poner ningún parámetro.

Comment: ¿es aceptable recargar la página?

Comment: No, cómo lo hago mediante AJAX quería que sólo subiera el valor de la gráfica.

Comment: Otra opción es: un botón que llame nuevamente la función que dibuja tu gráfica. Esta función debe limpiar todo el HTML que tenga el div que aloja la gráfica.

Answer (score 0):

Debes hacerlo con [reflow](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.reflow) es super sencillo.

> chart.reflow();

Answer (score 0):

este tipo de cambios se hacen con los métodos de axis como `setExtremes` o el util para todo `update`

ejemplo

```
var chart = $('#water_grafic').highcharts();
$('#submit_500ml').on('click', function() {
    chart.yAxis[0].update({
        min: 0,
        max: 5
    });
});
```

te dejo links de ayuda

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#update

https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/axis-update/